# android Google Cloud Messaging - permission denied for $ mv function

Tags: android, macos, google-cloud-messaging

Hey guys I'm trying again to use GCM (failed the first time) and I'm trying to use the

```
$ mv path-to-download/google-services.json app/"
```

command to move my json configuration file i downloaded from google developer as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client?configured=true)

unfortunately i get an error "permission denied", i tried few other command i found but nothing helped.
here is the terminal log:

```
Roee-Macbook:JapaneseQuickCourse sarigbrand$ $mv /Users/sarigbrand/Downloads/google-services.json app/
bash: /Users/sarigbrand/Downloads/google-services.json: Permission denied
Roee-Macbook:JapaneseQuickCourse sarigbrand$ chmod a+x android
chmod: android: No such file or directory
Roee-Macbook:JapaneseQuickCourse sarigbrand$ chmod +x /Users/sarigbrand/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android
Roee-Macbook:JapaneseQuickCourse sarigbrand$ $mv /Users/sarigbrand/Downloads/google-services.json app/
bash: /Users/sarigbrand/Downloads/google-services.json: Permission denied
Roee-Macbook:JapaneseQuickCourse sarigbrand$ $ mv /Users/sarigbrand/Downloads/google-services.json app/
bash: $: command not found
```

---

My os id - **OS X El Capitan v - 10.11.3**

Last time I failed at this as well so i just copy paste the file manually but maybe that's why it didn't work in the first time, any suggestions?

Comment: write abstrack path of google-services.json file

Comment: I beg your pardon? didn't understand what you just said

Comment: I'm also new to mac. this is my first one

Comment: I would just copy and past the file that's what I do and it works fine.

Comment: @TaylorCourtney I tried it last time as I said but project went all wrong so I thought that was the issue.

Comment: @TaylorCourtney I will give it another go since it worked for you, thank you.

Comment: Make sure to paste it in your app module near the build.gradle

Comment: @TaylorCourtney just to make sure is it the following path? - /Users/sarigbrand/AndroidStudioProjects/JapaneseQuickCourse/app

Comment: Did copy and paste help?

Comment: yes finally got it working today! thank you very much.

Comment: any good recommendation for xmpp guide? iI'm trying to build chat now and I figured xmpp is better then just http post? @TaylorCourtney

Comment: Please up vote I use post method